# How to set kubernetes secret key name when using --from-file other than filename?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, docker-secrets

Is there a way to set a kubernetes secret key name when using `--from-file` other than the filename?

I have a bunch of different configuration files that I use as `secrets.json` within my containers. However, to organize my files, none of them are named `secrets.json` on my host. For example `secrets.dev.json` or `secrets.test.json`. My apps only know to read in `secrets.json`.

When I create a secret with `kubectl create secret generic my-app-secrets --from-file=secrets.dev.json`, this results in the key name being `secrets.dev.json` and not `secrets.json`.

I'm mounting in my secret contents as a file (this is a carry-over from migrating from Docker swarm).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: my-secret
        secret:
          secretName: my-app-secrets
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-secret
              mountPath: "/run/secrets/secrets.json"
              subPath: "secrets.json"
```

Because `secrets.json` doesn't exist as a key because it used the filename (`secrets.dev.json`), it ends up getting turned into a directory instead. I end up getting this mount path: `/run/secrets/secrets.json/secrets.dev.json`.

I'd like to be able to set the key name to `secrets.json` instead of using the filename of `secrets.dev.json`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify key name `[--from-file=[key=]source]`

```
kubectl create secret generic my-app-secrets --from-file=secrets.json=secrets.dev.json
```

Here, `secrets.json` is key name and `secrets.dev.json` is source

Comment: This also works in a `kustomization.yaml` file:
`files:` 
`- secrets.json=secrets.dev.json`